# Click event handler on Userform

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I want to hide a ListBox Object within an Excel UserForm when a click is registered outside of the ListBox object. So I figured I use a Click or MouseUp event on the UserForm, but both do not seem to work. Is there any way I can achive this functionality?

What I have tried so far:

```
Sub TestUserForm_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)    
     If ListBoxSearch.Visible = True Then    
        ListBoxSearch.Visible = False    
     End If    
End Sub
```

And:

```
Sub TestUserForm_Click()    
     If ListBoxSearch.Visible = True Then    
        ListBoxSearch.Visible = False    
     End If    
End Sub
```

Both events do not fire.

Comment: Try `Me.Repaint` ?

Comment: No, where would I need to put that?

Comment: Put it after the `.Visible = False`

Comment: I've clarified the question. Both functions never execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
Sub UserForm_Click()    
     If ListBoxSearch.Visible = True Then    
        ListBoxSearch.Visible = False    
     End If    
End Sub
```

You dont use the actual name of the form to access its events. If you double click on the form in design mode, it will create the proper event for you.

Comment: If I double click on the form in design mode it jumps to the forms activate function ...

Comment: @plocks use the dropdowns at the top of the code pane to add handlers manually (without using the designer). The left-hand dropdown contains the available event providers / interfaces, the right-hand dropdown contains the available events / members for the selected event provider/interface.